# Android graphical layout on Eclipse - missing palette toolbar

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, palette

in my Eclipse installation I've lost the palette toolbar from where was possible to drag&drop widget on the Layout.
I'm currently opening layouts in Graphical Layout and can see everything (Structure browser, properties of widget) but no palette.
I've closed it for a mistake but now I'm no more able to open it again.
I tried to close and open Eclipse many times, I searched around in options but nothing.
What should I do? I'd like avoid to reinstall everything!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the following
1) Enlarge your Graphical Layout
2) Is your computer system language set to English? If not, switch it to English.
3) From the paleltte, click on the arrow pointing downwards and select "Refresh Preview"